# How to disable DB prefix name in mysql 6.3 Workbench

Tags: mysql, database

I want to disable database prefix name while executing queries in MySQL.

I am using `MySQl Workbench 6.3 CE`.

For Example : `SELECT * FROM test_db.test_table;`

I want to remove *test_db* prefix.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL workbench, in the lefthand pane, there is a list of available databases. If you're only using one, you can right click on it and select "set as default schema", then any queries you run in that MySQL session will no longer need to be prefixed with the DB name. However, if you want to query another DB in the same session, you will have to append that DB's name as a prefix, or do the same process, and set that DB as the default schema.

See this link for pretty pictures and a full description: https://www.quackit.com/mysql/tutorial/mysql_default_database.cfm

Comment: I feel like this is what op was looking for, at least thats why i am here

Comment: It probably works, but @Zak's answer below is the more programmatic way of doing it, especially if you're storing the SQL code somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell it what database to use .. So you do it the way you are describing. .. Or you tell MySQL which database to use BEFORE the `SELECT` IE

```
use test_db;
SELECT * FROM test_table;
```

Comment: Yeah I know it, Is there any other option to disable permanently in UI or through script, as I am running java program to execute the scripts I can't execute the use query for every script.

Comment: Your question says `Workbench`  -- `Java` is a whole other thing .. You'll need to declare your database in your connection string ..  Which you didn't post, or mention ..

Comment: Leave java, is there any other option to disable permanently without executing use query.

Comment: You are thinking about this wrong ...  MySQL can have an infinite number of databases, so you **need** to `SELECT` or `USE` your database at least initially to tell mySQL which database you are looking for ...  There is no "default" schema for incoming queries ..  It simply wouldn't know where to look!  There is no "disabling" which database to use --  That's like having a address, but no street name ..

Comment: Yeah I know we can create infinite no of DBs. But is there any way by selecting particular database settings and disable prefix so that when I connect the particular database prefix not necessary to execute use query. For example : I found one option in CPanel Mysql admin by [disabling  DB prefix name](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1142Docs/Disable+Database+Prefix)

Comment: @MohammedAbdullah There seems to be a misunderstanding: cpanel prefixes the database name itself with the username when you create new databases (e.g. it creates database `u981672_test` if you want to create a database `test`), that option disables this. `test_db.` in your query just specifies the database/schema to use in your query. If you select that database (e.g. in the connection string, or by `use test_db`), you do not need to specify that name: for every table in your query that has no "database prefix", MySQL will assume it's from the currently selected database; so just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

They way MySQL works is that you either explicitly state which schema a specific DB object is in (e.g. a table) or it uses the current default schema. If you don't have a default schema set and don't use fully qualfied names, you will get an error from MySQL saying that you have to define a default schema first.

So what you want to accomplish is impossible. Either set a default schema (it's a per connection setting, so you can set it once and use with your other queries as long as you keep the connection open) or fully qualify your DB objects (which is the most flexible approach and also avoids certain ambiquities, like same named tables in different schemas).